# dynamicType of optional chaining not the same as assignment

Tags: swift, swift2, dynamictype, optional-chaining

Optional chaining returns *always* an optional value.

> To reflect the fact that optional chaining can be called on a nil value, the result of an optional chaining call is always an optional value, even if the property, method, or subscript you are querying returns a nonoptional value.
>
> [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Why the heck does in a playground the type not optional?

```
let stringOptEmpty: String? = ""
stringOptEmpty?.isEmpty // is true
stringOptEmpty?.isEmpty.dynamicType // Bool.Type
```

But the following code is

```
let isOk = stringOptEmpty?.isEmpty.dynamicType
isOk.dynamicType // Optional<Bool.Type>.Type
```

Comment: The displayed temporary value in the realtime column sometimes can diverge from the real value especially when displaying non-assigned optional types. However the result of `print` expressions in the debug console displays always the correct type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TLDR;

The playground sidebar/column will dynamically resolve expressions in the playground, be it values assigned to *variables* (mutables/immutables) or just "free-floating" non-assigned values.

Your first example applies `dynamicType` to a *value*, which will resolve to the *type of that specific value* (`true.dynamicType`: `Bool.Type`).

Your second example, on the other hand, applies `dynamicType` to a *variable* (an immutable, but I'll use *variable* here to differ from *value*), which must have a concrete type, and hence will resolve to a type that can hold any kind of wrapped values (`true` or `false`) as well as `nil` (here, `nil` is, specifically, `Optional<Bool.Type>.None`), no matter what value the variable actually holds. Hence, the `dynamicType` will resolve to `Optional<Bool.Type>.Type` in your second example.

---

#### Details

The value displayed in the playground sidebar/column generally follows the following display rules:

- For an *assignment* expression, the value shown in the sidebar is the value assigned, e.g.

  ```
  var a = 4 // shows '4'
  a = 2     // shows '2'
  let b: () = (a = 3)
            /* shows '()': the _value_ assigned to 'b', which is the _result_
               of the assignment 'a = 3', to which a _side effect_ is that 'a'
               is assigned the value '3'. */
  ```
- For an expression that contains no assignment, the value shown in the sidebar is generally *the result of the expression*, e.g.

  ```
  true          // shows 'true'
  1 > 3         // shows 'false'
  let c = 3
  c             // shows '3'
  c.dynamicType // shows 'Int.Type'
  ```

In your first example (lines 2-3), we have no assignment, and the playground will dynamically resolve the *value*(/result) of the expression prior to resolving the `dynamicType` of that value. Since we're dealing with optionals, the *value* is either simply the value of the wrapped type (in this case, `true`), or the value is a *type specific* `.None`. Even if the playground shows e.g. the result of `let a: Int? = nil` as just `nil` in the sidebar, the value shown is in fact not the same `.None` (`nil`) as for say `let b: String = nil`

- For `let a: Int? = nil`, the ***value*** of `a` is in fact `Optional<Int.Type>.None`,
- whereas for `let b: String? = nil`, the ***value*** of `b` is `Optional<String.Type>.None`

With this in mind, it's natural that the resolved `dynamicType` of a non-`nil` *value* will be the concrete *wrapped* type (in your example, `Bool.Type` is naturally the type of `true`), whereas the resolved `dynamicType` of a `nil` value will include both the general optional and the wrapped type information.

```
struct Foo {
    let bar: Bool = true
}

var foo: Foo? = Foo()

/* .Some<T> case (non-nil) */
foo?.bar             // true <-- _expression_ resolves to (results in) the _value_ 'true'
foo?.bar.dynamicType // Bool.Type <-- dynamic type of the _result of expression_
true.dynamicType     // Bool.Type <-- compare with this

/* .None case (nil) */
foo = nil
foo?.bar.dynamicType // nil <-- _expression_ resolves to the _value_ 'Optional<Foo.Type>.None'
Optional<Foo.Type>.None.dynamicType
                     // Optional<Foo.Type>.Type <-- compare with this
```

Now, if you *assign* the values to a variable, naturally the variable must have a concrete type. Since the value we assign *at runtime* can be either `.None` or `.Some<T>`, the type of the variable must be one that can hold values of both these cases, hence, `Optional<T.Type>` (disregarding of whether the variable holds `nil` or a non-`nil` value). This is the case which you've shown in your second example: the `dynamicType` of the *variable* (here, immutable, but using *variable*  to differ from *value*) `isOk` is the type that can hold both `.None` and `.Some<T>`, no matter what the actual value of the variable is, and hence `dynamicType` resolves to this type; `Optional<Bool.Type>.Type`.

---

#### Wrapping expressions in parantheses escapes the runtime introspection of the Swift Playground?

Interestingly, if an expression is wrapped in parantheses prior to applying `.dynamicType`, then the playground sidebar resolves `.dynamicType` of the wrapped expression as the *type* of the expression, as if its actual value was unknown. E.g., `(...)` in `(...).dynamicType` is treated as a variable with a concrete type rather than a runtime-resolved value.

```
/* .Some case (non-nil) */
foo?.bar               // true
(foo?.bar).dynamicType /* Optional<Bool>.Type <-- as if (...) 
                          is a _variable_ of unknown value         */

/* .None case (nil) */
foo = nil
(foo?.bar).dynamicType /* Optional<Bool>.Type <-- as if (...) 
                          is a _variable_ of unknown value         */
```

We can further note that any lone expression wrapped in parantheses in the playground will not resolve to anything at all (in the sidebar). It's as if we escape the sidebar:s runtime introspection if wrapping expressions in parantheses (which would explain why the `dynamicType` of expressions wrapped in parantheses will resolve as if the playground cannot make use runtime information of these expressions)

```
var a = 4 // shows '4'
(a = 2)   // shows nothing; can't expand or get details in sidebar
```

Tbh, I cannot explain why this is, and will categorize it as a peculiarity of the Swift playground.